# How to make ESLint understand that function is used in vue pug template?

Tags: vue.js, pug, eslint, typescript-eslint

I have following vue component.

```
<template lang="pug">
button(@click="onLogout") Logout
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
function onLogout() {
  // some logic
}
</script>
```

When I run linter. Linter complains `Warning:(9, 10) ESLint: 'onLogout' is defined but never used. (@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars)`

How do I make ESLint aware that `onLogout` function is used in the template?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use [eslint-plugin-vue-pug](https://github.com/rashfael/eslint-plugin-vue-pug). This plugin extends [eslint-plugin-vue](https://eslint.vuejs.org/) to support pug templates. After installing you must add the plugin to your eslint config:

```js
module.exports = {
  extends: [
    'plugin:vue/vue3-recommended',
    'plugin:vue-pug/vue3-recommended'
  ]
}
```

The plugin only supports pug syntax that directly corresponds to html syntax. Some more details you can find on the description of rule [no-pug-control-flow](https://github.com/rashfael/eslint-plugin-vue-pug/blob/main/docs/rules/no-pug-control-flow.md).

Comment: Do you know if this only works with Vue3? I tried to add `plugin:vue-pug/strongly-recommended` and it didn't seem to work.

Comment: it works well with my vue3 project!